# SailsJS: Prevent Model.create() if it has undeclared attributes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

Is there a way to prevent an entity creation if it contains an attribute that is not declared in api/models/YourModel?

For example, let's say I used MongoDB, and I have this `User` model:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name:{type:'string'},
    age:{type:'number'}
  }
};
```

and I try to `.create` with this code:

```
User.create({name:'Walter Jr',age:8,missingTest:'something'}).exec(function createCB(err,created){
  console.log('should fail');
});
```

Also, if a have a relationship/association to another model, shouldn't creation fail as well if the entity id points to an invalid entity?

Maybe I'm missing something in the validation process, but so far the behaviour seems a bit strange to me, also it would be nice if waterline had composite primary key support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to put `schema : true` under config/models.js

Doc say :

> A flag to toggle schemaless or schema mode in databases that support schemaless data structures. If turned off, this will allow you to store arbitrary data in a record. If turned on, only attributes defined in the model's attributes object will be stored.
>   For adapters that don't require a schema, such as Mongo or Redis, the default setting is schema:false.

http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/model-settings.html

Comment: Sounds right, but I tried to write `schema: true` in `config/models.js` and it did nothing, strange.

Comment: Did you try to first clear your database and then restart your server ?

Comment: I set `migrate: 'drop'`, tried restarting `mongod`, no error returned on creation yet, also seen in the log that the db actually dropped.

Comment: If it helps, I'm using node version v0.10.38, MongoDB version 3.0.1

Comment: Figured, it ignores missing attributes instead of passing an error arg. so it works though not exactly the way I expected.

Comment: If you want to throw an error you can for each model override the method beforeValidate and check your model manually. http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Lifecyclecallbacks.html